# OCaml opam can't install any package

Tags: ocaml, opam

So opam seems to be installed correctly and on opam --version i get 1.2.2

But every time I try to install a package I get this error:

> opam install labltk (example)
>
> Fatal error:
>   OpamSystem.File_not_found("/home/phil/.opam/4.02.3/backup/state-20160326184335.export")

Comment: stupid question : is 'opam init' running fine ?

Comment: try ``rm ~/.opam/state.cache``?

Comment: yeah opam init was running fine. Thanks for your answers but I just reinstalled everything (ocaml and opam) and now it works fine. Still don't know what the problem was though

Answer (score -2):

Run command as root, please.

e.g. sudo opam install labltk